Weird bug in Mathematica 14.1 when importing and interpolating data
I am importing some data and interpolating it in Mathematica 14.1@Windows 11. I have made a block of code that does this. For some reason, there is a bug: if I leave the interpolation line uncommented inside the block, it quits the kernel. If I comment first, then evaluate the block, and then separately evaluate the interpolation, it crashes.
Unfortunately, I was not able to localize the problem to make it reproducible with a simpler example, so I provided my actual code below. There, I am importing .json and .mx files with a total file size lower than 1 Gb; the data is pure numbers. I have checked that neither CPU nor RAM usage exceeds 100%. If working, it would evaluate for 4-5 seconds. I am seeking general advice on what may be wrong.
importingGlobalNumbers[LLP_] := Module[{},
  folder = 
   FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "Output", LLP, 
     "Cluster output"}];
  filesJSON = FileNames["global-numbers_" <> LLP <> ".json", folder];
  filesMX = FileNames["global-numbers_" <> LLP <> ".mx", folder];
  If[filesMX != {},
   Import[filesMX[[1]], "MX"]
   ,
   Import[filesJSON[[1]], "JSON"]
   ]
  ]
IntDataLog[data_, LLP_, index_] := 
  Exp[Interpolation[Log[data[LLP][[All, {1, 2, index}]]], 
     InterpolationOrder -> 1][Log[m], Log[\[Tau]]]];
BlockInterpolation[LLP_] := Block[{},
  LLPsel = LLP;
  (*Importing dataset 1*)
  OutputLLPintegrated[LLPsel] = 
   Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
      "Output/" <> LLPsel <> "/final-values-" <> LLPsel <> ".mx"}], 
    "MX"];
  (*Dropping the part with decay probabilities*)
  GlobalNumbersLLP[LLPsel] = OutputLLPintegrated[LLPsel][[All, 1]];
  (*Making interpolations of various quantities*)
  {nLLPin[LLPsel, m_, \[Tau]_], 
    NeffIntegratedInt[LLPsel, m_, \[Tau]_], 
    r1LLP[LLPsel, m_, \[Tau]_], r2LLP[LLPsel, m_, \[Tau]_], 
    r3LLP[LLPsel, m_, \[Tau]_]} = 
   IntDataLog[GlobalNumbersLLP, LLPsel, #] & /@ {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  \[CapitalDelta]NeffIntegratedInt[LLPsel, m_, \[Tau]_] = 
   NeffIntegratedInt[LLPsel, m, \[Tau]] - 3.035;
  {mminmax[LLPsel], \[Tau]minmax[LLPsel], r1minmax[LLPsel], 
    r2minmax[LLPsel], r3minmax[LLPsel]} = 
   MinMax[GlobalNumbersLLP[LLPsel][[All, #]]] & /@ {1, 2, 5, 6, 7};
  (*Importing the output of Unint's code*)
  OutputLLPUnint[LLPsel] = importingGlobalNumbers[LLPsel];
  NeffUnintData[LLPsel] = OutputLLPUnint[LLPsel][[All, {1, 2, -1}]];
  NeffUnintInt[LLPsel, m_, \[Tau]_] = 
   IntDataLog[NeffUnintData, LLPsel, -1];
  ]

I execute it as
Do[
  BlockInterpolation[LLPsel]
  , {LLPsel, {"pt1", "pt2", "pt3"}}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming

The problem is with the last string of the second block. However, if I comment out some of the previous strings, it then works without problems. Another weird thing is that Mathematica 13.2 works well with this code.

(1) I'm sure you already know that the tag [bugs] should not be placed on new questions. (2) If we cannot reproduce the problem, it is very difficult to provide any explanation or solution. Just write to the technical support.

@Domen : as I have specified in the question, I am looking for generic advice. For a person who understands Mathematica deeply in this particular aspect, the description may be enough.

@JohnTaylor There's usually nothing you can do in these situations, except 1) contacting technical support 2) implementing your code differently, or even breaking out to a different language. Check if the numbers exact or floating point... sometimes exact numbers will cause problems.

Some random observations of your code. You have not localized any variables in Module[{x,y,..}, ...] and Block[{},]. Therefore all variables are global. Next, you call BlockInterpolation[LLPsel] in the Do[]-loop, but the first line in the function definition is BlockInterpolation[LLP_] := Block[{}, LLPsel = LLP; . There might be some screw-up between the LLPsel and LLP variables.

@RomkeBontekoe : thanks! But it does not happen in 13.2.

@flinty : thanks!
